# Beamer Poster Gemini: How to add multiple logo in each side

Tags: beamer, posters, beamerposter

I am using the [gemini beamer poster](https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini) template. The current functionality only allows to add one logo per each side of left and right at the top using `\logoright` and `\logoleft`. However, I need to add 6 logos; so ideally 3 logos per side. In each side, I would like to add three logos such that in the first row there are two logos, and in the second row there will be the third logo centered. How can I define such command?

```
% Gemini theme
% https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini

% ====================
% Dependencies
% ====================

\RequirePackage{exscale}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{calc}

% ====================
% Fonts
% ====================

\newfontfamily\Raleway[Ligatures=TeX]{Raleway}
\newfontfamily\Lato[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\setsansfont{Lato}[
  UprightFont=*-Light,
  ItalicFont=*-LightItalic,
  BoldFont=*-Regular,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Italic
]

\setbeamerfont{headline}{family=\Raleway}
\setbeamerfont{headline title}{size=\Huge,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{headline author}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{headline institute}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{family=\Raleway,size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{heading}{family=\Lato,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{family=\Raleway,size=\normalsize}

% ====================
% Macros
% ====================

\newcommand{\samelineand}{\qquad}

% ====================
% Elements
% ====================

% List
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
\topsep 1ex % spacing before
\parsep 0\p@ \@plus\p@
\itemsep 0.5ex} % spacing between

% Itemize

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raise0.5ex \hbox{\vrule width 0.5ex height 0.5ex}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raise0.3ex \hbox{\vrule width 0.5ex height 0.5ex}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\raise0.2ex \hbox{\vrule width 0.5ex height 0.5ex}}

% Enumerate

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\insertenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\insertsubenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{\insertsubsubenumlabel.}

% Equation
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex}

% Caption
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[period]
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}

% Bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

% Navigation
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

% ====================
% Components
% ====================

% Heading
\newcommand\heading[1]
{%
  \par\bigskip
  {\usebeamerfont{heading}\usebeamercolor[fg]{heading}#1}\par\smallskip
}

% logo
\newlength{\logoleftwidth}
\setlength{\logoleftwidth}{0cm}
\newlength{\logorightwidth}
\setlength{\logorightwidth}{0cm}
\newlength{\maxlogowidth}  % space on both sides set to maxlogowidth to keep title centered
\setlength{\maxlogowidth}{0cm}

\newcommand{\logoright}[1]{
  \newcommand{\insertlogoright}{#1}
  \settowidth{\logorightwidth}{\insertlogoright}
  \addtolength{\logorightwidth}{10ex}
  \setlength{\maxlogowidth}{\maxof{\logoleftwidth}{\logorightwidth}}
}
\newcommand{\logoleft}[1]{
  \newcommand{\insertlogoleft}{#1}
  \settowidth{\logoleftwidth}{\insertlogoleft}
  \addtolength{\logoleftwidth}{10ex}
  \setlength{\maxlogowidth}{\maxof{\logoleftwidth}{\logorightwidth}}
}

% Headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{headline}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{\maxlogowidth}
        \vskip5ex
        \ifdefined\insertlogoleft
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \hspace{10ex}
        \raggedright
        \insertlogoleft
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \else\fi
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\maxlogowidth-\maxlogowidth}
        \usebeamerfont{headline}
        \vskip3ex
        \centering
        \ifx \inserttitle \empty \else
        {\usebeamerfont{headline title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{headline title}\inserttitle\\[0.5ex]}
        \fi
        \ifx \beamer@shortauthor \empty \else
        {\usebeamerfont{headline author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{headline author}\insertauthor\\[1ex]}
        \fi
        \ifx \insertinstitute \empty \else
        {\usebeamerfont{headline institute}\usebeamercolor[fg]{headline institute}\insertinstitute\\[1ex]}
        \fi
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{\maxlogowidth}
        \vskip5ex
        \ifdefined\insertlogoright
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \raggedleft
        \insertlogoright
        \hspace{10ex}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \else\fi
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vspace{5ex}
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{headline rule}{}{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=0.5ex]{headline rule}\end{beamercolorbox}
    }
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% Block
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block body}
  \justifying
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}
{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

% Alert Block
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block alerted title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block alerted separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block alerted body}
  \justifying
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block alerted end}
{
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

% Example Block
\setbeamertemplate{block example begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block example title}
    \vskip0pt
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block example separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block example body}
  \justifying
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block example end}
{
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

% Footer
\newcommand{\footercontent}[1]{\newcommand{\insertfootercontent}{#1}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \ifdefined\insertfootercontent
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[vmode]{headline}
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{headline rule}{}{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=0.25ex]{headline rule}\end{beamercolorbox}
    }
    \vspace{1.5ex}
    \hspace{\sepwidth}
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \centering
    \insertfootercontent
    \hspace{\sepwidth}
    \vspace{1.5ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \else\fi
}
```

Comment: Please always include a compilable test document in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place more than one image in `\logoleft/right`. Here an example with three images in `\logoright`, I'm sure you can adapt this for `\logoleft` yourself.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[size=a2]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{gemini}

\logoright{%
  \parbox{13cm}{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
    \par
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
  }
}


\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! But when I try it, the three logos appear in one vertical column. I used this overleaf template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/gemini-poster-theme/nzpspqjryjhx

Comment: @melatonin15 I used the theme from your question. Can you show your .log file?

Comment: Here it is https://pastecode.io/s/03dirp0z

Comment: I also tried by directly importing the github repo in overleaf and modifying the code as per your answer. But the same problem still lingers.

Comment: Seems to work fine with your overleaf template, too: https://www.overleaf.com/read/cpqbgymwqzxp#9dbb6d

Comment: Interesting. Basically when I try to use your answer with the original poster.tex template it gives issues https://www.overleaf.com/2588914298pczfwvtgtpwv#069522

Comment: @melatonin15 You are using a different paper size. Adjust the value of `13cm` as needed. Or add a minimal working test document to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!